# node.js post api returns old response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using express post api for login a user, the problem is it returns the previous post response.

I dont know what wrong thing I am doing.

Here is my app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');
// var lusca = require('lusca');
var db = require('./db.config');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
//this or other session management will be required
app.use(session({
 secret: 'Qwaszx',
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
/**
 * CSRF
 */
// app.use(lusca({
//   csrf: true,
  // csp: { /* ... */},
  // xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  // p3p: 'ABCDEF',
  // hsts: {maxAge: 31536000, includeSubDomains: true, preload: true},
  // xssProtection: true,
  // nosniff: true,
  // referrerPolicy: 'same-origin'
// }));

/**
 * CSRF Token
 */
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

/**
 * Routes
 */
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/admin', admin);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

and my auth.js route file is under routes directory which is as below:
where I am posting login and getting old response all the time time I do not quit the server and restart it.

```js
var express       = require('express');
var router        = express.Router();
var userModel     = require('../model/user.model');
var session       = require('express-session');
var auth          = require('../middleware');

/**
 * Get register API
 */
router.get('/register', auth.Auth, function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('auth/register', { title: 'Register a new user' });
});

/**
 * Post register API
 */
router.post('/register', auth.Auth, function (req, res, next) {

  if(req.body.password === req.body.c_password ){ //password match

    userModel.create(req.body).then(function (result){//Create user
      
      res.redirect('/auth/login');
    }).catch( function (err) {

      res.redirect('/auth/register');
    });
  }
  else{

    res.redirect('/auth/register');
  }
});

/**
 * Get login API
 */
router.get('/login', auth.Auth, function (req, res, next) {
    
  res.render('auth/login');
});

/**
 * Post login API
 */
router.post('/login', auth.Auth, function (req, res, next) {

  userModel.login(JSON.stringify(req.body)).then( function(resp) {

    // console.log(resp);
    req.session.user = {
      user_id   : resp.user_id,
      user_type : resp.user_type,
    };
    // res.send(resp);
    res.json(resp);   
    // res.redirect('/auth/login')
  }).catch(function (err){
    // console.log(err);
    res.json(err);
    // res.redirect('/auth/login')
  });
});

/**
 * Logout API
 */
router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {

  return userModel.logout(req.session.user.user_id).then(function (result) {
    
    // console.log("result = " + result);
    delete req.session.user;

    res.redirect('/auth/login');
  }).catch(function(err){
      
    // console.log(err);
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

now my model file where I put database interface is user.model.js is uder model directory which is shown below:

```js
var connection      = require('../db.config');
var randomstring    = require("randomstring");
var passwordHash    = require('password-hash');
var q               = require('q');
var deferred        = q.defer();

model               = {};
model.index         = index;
model.create        = create;
model.show          = show;
model.login         = login;
model.logout        = logout;
model.adminLogin    = adminLogin;
module.exports  = model;

/**
 * Show all users
 */
function index(){

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users  as U JOIN logs as L ON U.id = L.user_id  WHERE U.user_type != "1" ORDER BY L.id DESC', function(error, response){

        if(error) deferred.reject(error);

        if(response.length > 0){ 
            // console.log(response);
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
        else{

            deferred.resolve([]);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

/**
 * Create a new user
 * 
 * @param {*array} data 
 */
function create(data){

    var hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(data.password);
    var user = {
        'email'             : data.email,
        // 'user_name'         : data.user_name,
        'mac_add'           : data.mac_add,
        'password'          : hashedPassword,
        'verification_code' : randomstring.generate(10),
        '_token'            : data._csrf, 
    }
    //Check user is already exists or not
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' + user.email + '" LIMIT 0,1', function(error, result) {

        if(error) {

            deferred.reject(error);
        }
        
        if(result[0]){

            deferred.reject('Email ' + result[0].email + ' is already taken. Please try with another email.');
        }
        else{

            return createUser();
        }
    });
    //Create User
    function createUser() {

        connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ', user , function (error, response){
            if(error) {
             
                console.log(error);
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            else{
    
                console.log(response);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
/**
 * Show user details
 * 
 * @param {*number} id 
 */
function show(id){

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = "' + id + '"', function(error, response) {

        if(error) deferred.reject(error);

        if(response[0]) deferred.resolve(response[0]);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

/**
 * Login user using email, password and mac address
 * 
 * @param {* array} data 
 */
function login(data){

    var userData = JSON.parse(data);
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' + userData.email + '" LIMIT 0,1', function(error, response) {

        if(error) deferred.reject(error);
        //check if user exists
        if(response.length > 0){
            
            if(passwordHash.verify(userData.password, response[0].password)){//password matching

                // Validate that an address is a mac address 
                if(response[0].user_type === 0){
                    
                    console.log(response[0]);
                    deferred.resolve(response[0]);
                    // if ( require('getmac').isMac(response[0].mac_add) ) {

                    //     // var res = JSON.parse(result[0]);
                    // return createLog(response[0].id, response[0].user_type);
                    // }
                    // else{

                    //     deferred.reject('Unauthorized System!');
                    // }
                }
                // else{

                //     var result = {
                //         'user_id'   : response[0].id,
                //         'user_type' : response[0].user_type,
                //     }

                //     deferred.resolve(result);
                // }
            }
            else{

                deferred.reject('Invalid credential');
            }
        }
        else{

            deferred.reject('User not found');
        }
    });
    /**
     * Create user logs
     * 
     * @param {*numeric} user_id 
     */
    function createLog(user_id, user_type){
        
        var log = {
            
            'user_id'       : user_id,
            // 'in_time'       : new Date(),
        }
        result = {
            'user_id'     : user_id,
            'user_type'   : user_type,
        }
        connection.query('INSERT INTO logs SET ? ', log, function(err, resp) {
            
            if(err) deferred.reject(err);

            if(resp) deferred.resolve(result);
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
/**
 * Logout out time entry
 * 
 * @param {*number} user_id 
 */
function logout(user_id){

    //Get row id of current log from logs table
    connection.query('SELECT id FROM logs where user_id = "' + user_id + '" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1', function(err, resp){

        if(err) deferred.reject(err);
        
        if(resp[0]){
                // console.log(result[0].id);
            return updateLog(resp[0].id); //updating time
        }else{

            deferred.reject("No logs");
        }
    });

    function updateLog(id){ // update the out time

        // var out_time = new Date();
        // console.log(out_time);
        connection.query('UPDATE logs SET signature = "shift end", status = "1" WHERE id = ' + id, function(error, response) {
            
            if(error) deferred.reject(error);
            if(response) deferred.resolve(response);
        });
        // console.log(query.sql);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
    
}

/**
 * Admin Login
 * 
 * @param {*array} data 
 */
function adminLogin(data){

    var userData = JSON.parse(data);
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "' + userData.email + '" AND user_type = "1" LIMIT 1', function(error, response) {

        if(error) deferred.reject(error);
        //check if user exists
        if(response.length > 0){
            
            if(passwordHash.verify(userData.password, response[0].password)){//password matching
                // console.log("admin response = " + response[0]);
                deferred.resolve(response[0]);
            }
            else{

                deferred.reject('Invalid Credential');
            }
        }
        else{

            deferred.reject('Unauthorized user');
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise
}
```

Now I want to know what wrong thing I am doing.
If I am hanging the node server and restarting it again then it works fine otherwise it returns same error or success response with the different credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Robert your answer was correct exactly. Thanks so much.
The soulution was to make seperate promise for each and every function.

I was using deferred = q.defer(); at the top of the page as globaly

So I have to remove it from here and put it seperately in each function.

Like

```js
function index(){
  
  deferred = q.defer();
  ....
  ......
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

this was the correct solution thanks alot robert

Thanks